# Liferay Portal hosting on a n ubuntu server

Tags: tomcat, liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to install liferay on a Ubuntu server. I'm folowing this tutorial[Installation and Configuration of a Liferay Portal on a 
Ubuntu Server](https://kenai.com/downloads/envision/Installation%20and%20Configuration%20Guides/Installation%20and%20Configuration%20of%20Liferay%20on%20Ubuntu%20Server.pdf)

when I finished, I tryed to start the server by executing ./startup.sh.

I got this error in yhe log file: catalina.out:

```
Java.net.BindException: Adress Already in use <null>:8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means some other application/service is using the same port which is causing a conflict. So change the tomcats default HTTP port from 8080 to something else, like 8081 for example.
Restart your server after this change.

```
It's in /tomcat-home/conf/server.xml

Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```